# When does Windows Error Reporting create a dump file? Is it configurable? Has this changed in Windows 7?

Tags: c++, windows, crash-reports, windows-error-reporting

I'm relying on [Windows Error Reporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create full user-mode dumps for a large, multi-threaded application.  I know that when I started using it (early 2012) these dumps contained all application memory, and full stacks for all threads that were accurate for the time the application crashed (threw the unhandled exception, etc).  But at at some unknown point in the last year, crash dumps created by WER have changed.  They still contain all memory, but only show one thread, and the stack appears to be from **after** the process is already shutting down:

```
    ntdll.dll!_LdrpCallInitRoutine@16()  + 0x14 bytes   
    ntdll.dll!_LdrShutdownProcess@0()  + 0x141 bytes    
    ntdll.dll!_RtlExitUserProcess@4()  + 0x74 bytes 
    kernel32.dll!_UnhandledExceptionFilter@4()  + 0x18928 bytes
```

This is an unmanaged (unmanagable?) 32-bit C++ application compiled with VS2010 SP1, running on 64-bit Win7 SP1 (and kept updated).  Does anyone know of any Windows updates that have changed WER behavior in the last year?  Is there something configurable other than 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\AppName.exe'?

Also, killing the application by calling 'RaiseFailFastException' still results in a good dump with valid stacks for all threads.

Comment: Nothing I heard.  The simple explanation is that your app is just crashing for a different reason.

Comment: No, I am explicitly throwing an exception to test the dump creation, and I am missing stacks on both the latest version of the application and the version from a year ago that originally worked.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aha!  A third-party library was calling SetUnhandledExceptionFilter, which prevented Windows Error Reporting from getting the original exception.  Their handler did some internal cleanup, then called abort, at which point WER was finally able to create a dump.

For anyone encountering this sort of problem, I recommend checking that the installed handlers (the return values of SetUnhandledExceptionFilter, set_terminate, etc) are what you expect (null if you're relying on WER, or your own handlers or CrashRpt).

Answer (score -1):

It is better to make your application self-dump-writer when it crashes. You just need to call [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, specify the call back. In the call back, use [MiniDumpWriteDump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with `MiniDumpWithFullMemory` dump type.

Your exception filter will be called whenever unhandled (by your code) exception occurs. In the call back, it will be better to enumerate and suspend all other threads of your process.

You may also need to install a hook for `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` itself! Why? Well, **CRT would always disable** any installed exception filter, and by the hooked function, you may avoid that.

Comment: Looks like this is what I'll have to do.  I'll go back to using the [CrashRpt](https://code.google.com/p/crashrpt/) library.

Comment: If it is feasible to rely on the WER dumps (i.e. no additional stuff needed in the unhandled filter, no specific user notification), using WER is *way better* (if you don't have to support WinXP). It will give you a dump in *all* crash scenarios, even corrupted stack where UHEF isn't even called. Plus: (quote MS) *MiniDumpWriteDump should be called from a separate process if at all possible, rather than from within the target process being dumped(...)* And I can tell you that this really gets complicated.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to say that this is a piece of an extremely bad advice. @MartinBa correctly points to the docs, but the docs do not tell *why* one should not do that. In fact, `MiniDumpWriteDump` calls `LoadLibraryEx()` internally, and, if you happen to be holding the loader lock, the process inevitably deadlocks inside the call. [This discussion thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/microsoft.public.windbg/Kca8A-pV914/UEd48t2OzccJ) has a good explanation from one of the WER developers why this is simply unavoidable.